# How to create a SQL query to save object if another does not exist in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity object that I am trying to save into a MySQL db. I am using an interface that implements the JpaRepository. I want to write a query that will save an object *if* certain fields of said object DO NOT match the corresponding fields of already saved objects.

I have the following query that will achieve this

```
insert into tableA(col_1,col_2,col_3) 
  select 'string_1','string_2','string_3'
  where not exists(select col_1 
                   from tableA
                   where col_1='string_1')
```

How can I translate this to work with the JpaRepository?

Comment: You certainly could do it using some SQL conditional statements but, it's much better for a number of reasons to move that kind of logic to the Service level (i.e. separation of concerns, much easier to code conditionals on Java.. etc..). Unless of course you have some kind of restrictions or you just want to practice SQL.

Comment: I see. So I first check whether there's an object currently in the db with col_1 = 'string_1', then based on that fact, choose to save or not save the object?

Comment: Exactly. First you will create a method to search for already existing entries that satisfy the condition you want. (take a look here for JPA named queries https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.named-queries). 

And then depending on you findings you could save your new entity instance using the CRUD repository as described here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.named-queries